# Help with developing equation with combinatorial numbers

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How can I get from $$k^{4} = a*\binom{k}{1}+b*\binom{k}{2}+c*\binom{k}{3}+d*\binom{k}{4}$$ to
\begin{equation}
 k^{4} = \frac{(24a-12b+8c-6d)k+(12b-12c+11d)k^{2}+(4c-6d)k^{3}+dk^{4}}{4!}
\end{equation}
I know that for example, $$\binom{k}{1}== \frac{k!}{1!*(k-1)!}$$
but I can not figure what steps were exactly made. Thank you very much.

Comment: $\displaystyle \binom{k}{r} = \frac{k(k-1)\cdots(k-r+1)}{r!}$ for $1 \le r \le k$, expand RHS as a polynomial in $k$ and gather the coefficients of similar powers of $k$ together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of ${k\choose n}$ is correct, but we can write it in another way which is helpful for this question, namely: $${k \choose n} = \frac{k(k-1)\cdots(k-(n-1))}{n!}.$$

As such, we can then rewrite your equation as: $$k^4 = a\left(\frac{k}{1!}\right) + b\left(\frac{k(k-1)}{2!}\right) + c\left(\frac{k(k-1)(k-2)}{3!}\right) + d\left(\frac{k(k-1)(k-2)(k-3)}{4!}\right).$$

If we factorize the 4! out (to make life easier, and so we get it in the form you are after) that is the same as: $$k^4 = \left(\frac{1}{4!}\right)\left(24ak + 12bk(k-1) + 4ck(k-1)(k-2) + dk(k-1)(k-2)(k-3)\right).$$

Multiply out all the brackets: $$k^4 = \left(\frac{1}{4!}\right)\left(24ak + 12bk^2 - 12bk + 4ck^3 -12ck^2 + 8ck + dk^4 - 6dk^3 + 11dk^2 -6dk\right).$$

Then I'll just rearrange this line, so the coefficients of $k$ are together: $$k^4 = \left(\frac{1}{4!}\right)(24ak - 12bk + 8ck - 6dk + 12bk^2 - 12ck^2 + 11dk^2 + 4ck^3 - 6dk^3 + dk^4).$$

Then just factorize the $k$'s: $$k^4 = \left(\frac{1}{4!}\right)((24a - 12b + 8c -6d)k + (12b - 12c + 11d)k^2 + (4c - 6d)k^3 +dk^4.)$$

Which is what you were after: $$k^4 = \frac{(24a - 12b + 8c -6d)k + (12b - 12c + 11d)k^2 + (4c - 6d)k^3 +dk^4}{4!}.$$